# How to group a list of titles by the first letter with linguistic rules?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of game titles that I am trying to display. Using `OrderBy()` sorts the list according to title rules for the current culture, so for en-US I get a list like this:

- **A**rthur's Game
- The **B**est Game Ever
- **C**arl's Game
- **D**avid's Game
- **E**arnest's Game
- An **E**ven Better Game

That's great and exactly what I want.

But how do I take this list and group it by the first letter (the letter in bold), in a culture-sensitive way? More specifically, how do I get the actual string that `OrderBy()` used to sort the list this way?

I tried looking at `System.Globalization.SortKey.OriginalString` but it just returned the same string it was given.

I know I can always take the sloppy way out and just trim "A", "An" and "The" from the start of the string, but I was hoping .Net had a way to hook into its culture-sensitive sorting logic for a more robust solution.

**Edit:** It looks like I was mistaken, and `GroupBy()` does not, in fact, sort that way. I messed up with my sample list. So It looks like I will have to just trim away the "A", "An", and "The" prefixes. Thanks to @stuartd for pointing out my error.

Comment: Would you mind showing the code that sorts by title that way? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @stuartd wow, I checked my sample code, and you're totally right. `OrderBy()` isn't sorting that way. That's probably why I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any already implemented solution to sort the titles like required. Since the words you could exclude are not so many (as I believe), you could define your own list of exclusions like

```
List<string> exclusions = new List<string>()
{
    "the", "an", "a",
};
```

Based on this exclusions you could order your titles (case insensitive in this implementation) using a simple query ignoring the exlusions you defined:

```
var orderedTitles = titles.OrderBy(
    t => string.Join(" ", t.Split(' ')
        .Where(s => !exclusions.Any(x => x.Equals(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))));
```

The idea is to split the title by spaces, and join it together without the excluded words. After that a simple order by does the job.

- A **simple track1**
- A **simple** a **track2**

If you only need to ignore all exclusions until the first non-excluded word, you could improve the query by using `Skip`.

```
var result = titles.OrderBy(
    t => string.Join(" ", t.Split(' ')
        .SkipWhile(s => exclusions.Any(x => x.Equals(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))));
```

- A **simple a track2**
- A **simple track1**